# How to populate fields based on Post Codes

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

So this is a googlesheet i made it, its basically like match making spreadsheet, the tab to look at is Host Create Listing and Guest Request to Stay, so i just need able to match the Guest and the host those who are having the common post code in them.

I have tried using the `FILTER` function however its not working. What should be the right function here to use to get those matched in the **MATCH MAKING** SHEET?

[MATCHMAKING_SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fS6zVI1Khb96g7wUVrRCPKceXqV0z7XGSsg4pRr3eAc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER(
 'Guest Request to Stay'!A2:A20&" "&'Guest Request to Stay'!B2:B20, 
 'Guest Request to Stay'!H2:H20<>""), VLOOKUP(FILTER(
 'Guest Request to Stay'!H2:H20, 'Guest Request to Stay'!H2:H20<>""), 
 {'Host Create Listing'!I2:I9, 'Host Create Listing'!C2:C9&" "&
  'Host Create Listing'!D2:D9, 'Host Create Listing'!I2:I9}, {2, 3}, 0)})
```

[image]